# "Not Enough Image Data" Error when Converting CV2 Numpy Array into RGB Image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

In the code below, I am attempting to output a single face (cropped from a larger image) with CV2:

```
def machine_pst():
    mlimg = request.files.get("mlimg")
    fname = mlimg.filename
    filepath = "/home/assets/faces/"
    mlimg.save(filepath + fname, overwrite = True)
    full_path = filepath + fname
    cascPath = "/home/assets/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
    faceSamples=[]
    pilImage=Image.open(full_path).convert('L')
    imageNp=np.array(pilImage,'uint8')
    faces=detector.detectMultiScale(imageNp)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        faceSamples.append(imageNp[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    img = Image.fromarray(faceSamples[0], 'RGB')

   cv2.imwrite("/home/assets/faces/read.png", img)
   source = "/static/faces/read.png"
   return template("home/machineout", source = source)
```

With *source* being passed as a parameter into img src="{{source}}

If I return the length of faces in an image with 3 faces, I get "3", so that seems to work nicely and if I return any index of faceSamples (e.g. faceSamples[0]), I get data returned as well, but when I try to turn that face sample into an image using ...

```
img = Image.fromarray(faceSamples[0], 'RGB')
```

I get a ValueError that there is "not enough image data"

I understand (from a previous answer) that detectMultiScale returns rectangles, not images, but with my additional Numpy code, is that still the case? Am I still not fully understanding what the faceSamples array is returning? Can this not be directly turned back into an RGB image with the last snippet of code?

Comment: I'm wondering if `"/home/.../assets/faces/"` is a correct path. Are you sure it's not `..`?

Comment: Ah sorry Quang. Let me remove those, so there's no confusion... I meant those dots just as an example. The paths all work fine

Comment: `img = Image.fromarray()` will try to make a PIL image which you then pass to `cv2.imwrite()` but OpenCV doesn't work with PIL images - it expects Numpy arrays. You already have what you want in `faceSamples[0]` - a Numpy array/image that OpenCV can use.

Comment: You rock Mark! I am currently looking at a single face from my image! Thanks for all the help and if you want to put this as the answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
pilImage=Image.open(full_path).convert('L')
imageNp=np.array(pilImage,'uint8')
```

That is, you converted `imageNp` into a single channel, gray image. Then it makes little sense to do

```
img = Image.fromarray(faceSamples[0], 'RGB')
```

as `faceSamples[0]` is also a gray image.

Also, like @MarkSetchell's comment, you can use `cv2.imread` and other functions instead of `PIL`. They are more compatible with other openCV functions.

Comment: Thanks Quang! That's good information regarding the gray image